# Fault detected on drive 0 in disk drive bay 1

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-server-2019, dell-poweredge

Under the circumstances where our system operates Windows Server 2019 on a Dell PowerEdge R440 server and displays the error message:

> Fault detected on drive 0 in disk drive bay 1

The hard disks in these servers are set up in a RAID 6 configuration.

While conducting a test on the hard disks, I encountered these errors.

Physical disk state Failed
[image]

EFI Device Error
[image]

Comment: This means a writefault on the disk, as in, the disk is probably bad. You should check the RAID controller software to find out more info, possibly do a SMART check on the drive itself, and consider replacing the drive.

Comment: Thanks for your response. While conducting tests on the hard disk, I encountered these errors, which are outlined in the question.

Comment: @sjarasan “Thanks for your response. While conducting tests on the hard disk, I encountered these errors, which are outlined in the question.” This sounds like gibberish. This is a simple case where the drive in a RAID array is dead. Remove the drive and swap it out for a good one. It should immediately rebuild the RAID array and all should go back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the message "Fault detected on drive 0 in disk drive bay 1"

This is an indication that there's a problem with either a disk, or the array.

In the comments, I wrote:

> This means a writefault on the disk, as in, the disk is probably bad. You should check the RAID controller software to find out more info, possibly do a SMART check on the drive itself, and consider replacing the drive.

You did this and added images that show that drive 0 is dead. The fact that it is not even capable of showing the correct disk size probably means the controller on the disk itself died.

The data on the disk cannot be retrieved, and the disk needs to be replaced.

Depending on how your configuration is, and what you do, you may lose all data, and for that reason, it is highly recommended to backup everything you have now before replacing the disk, as the disk appears to be part of an array.

I've had my HP Server complain when I accidentally removed the wrong disk and placed it back again that the array no longer was working and needed to be initialized, which removed everything from the disks.

Better safe than sorry.

After you have your backup and verified that you can restore them, replace the disk with a new one.

Comment: I am grateful for the information.